# SCDF Kubernetes scheduling with existing Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are working on a new deployment of SCDF in our Kubernetes environment. The new SCDF is supposed to schedule and run some Spring-batch containers.

We know that in order to do that, an application needs to be created with a path to the Docker Container, which then spins up a POD when the task is scheduled.

However, our requirement is that we need to point the application/task to an existing Kubernetes POD (containing the Spring-Batch containers).

So question is: Is this possible in SCDF? if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by `we need to point the application/task to an existing Kubernetes POD (containing the Spring-Batch containers)`? You are not supposed to point or tell K8S/SCDF to do that. What you need to do is ask SCDF to create a task and it will deploy it as a job on K8S. You should not be concerned on how or where the application is being deployed on the cluster.

Comment: OK, but what if we want to specify resources that the POD consumes (like CPU Memory) . How would we go about it? Is there a way for the SCDF to read a deployment.yaml file that contains these properties?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine .. Any clue?

Comment: That's a different question. You can use the `limits.cpu` and `limits.memory` properties for that, as mentioned in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-deployer.

Comment: As pointed out in the [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4331#issuecomment-762542980), SCDF doesn't automatically probe to inventory existing pods/jobs. You must define and launch task/jobs from SCDF to begin with, and you can alter CPU/memory and other properties when scheduling them from SCDF.